# zendframework2 : How to pass a parameter from one controller to another

Tags: php, zend-framework2

There was a similar thread but it didn't address this exact problem so I thought I would create a new thread to make this clear.

Code/problem explained:

This is my SystemsController.

Here I have viewsystemAction().  This is loaded, and from the view a script is called to load ajaxviewsystemAction().

In the viewsystemAction(), I use the params function to get the "id" parameter from my route.  For example systems/viewsystems/222     ( <-- 222 is id.  ).  I echo this out just to show that it is correct, and it gives the correct id for the page.

The ajaxviewsystemsAction is kind of where the problem is.  This is because the route of ajaxviewsystemsAction id is not the same as viewsystemsAction.  If I echo the id from the params here, it displays as 0.

Although if i go to this page in the browser for example ajaxviewsystemsAction/222 then it is working perfectly.  However, nothing is rendered here except the ajax table, as remember it is called in viewsystemAction from a script.

What i need to do, is somehow pass the id route value from viewsystemAction into ajaxviewsystemAction, to both use this same route id.

This is so when someone clicks on the link, it loads viewsystems/222, the correct id is executed in both viewsystemsAction and ajaxviewsystemsAction.

Is this possible?  If not how could i make something similar like this.  I am using zftable which integrates ajax.  I need to pass this id parameter through into a query.

```
   private function getSourceViewAllSystems($id)
    {   
         return $this->getSystemsTable()->fetchViewAllSystems($id); //paramater to model which executes sql ->where system = $id
    }

   public function viewsystemAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
        echo $id; //i see the correct id for example 220 from the route in the browser
    }

   public function ajaxviewsystemAction()

    {
       $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
       echo $id; //to see the id of the route with the ajax page
       //displays 0 and not the route id from the viewsystemAction

        $table = new TableExample\Advance();
        $table->setAdapter($this->getDbAdapter())
                ->setSource($this->getSourceViewAllSystems($id))
                ->setParamAdapter($this->getRequest()->getPost())
        ;
        return $this->htmlResponse($table->render('custom' , 'custom-b2'));

    }
```

--- update ---

```
    <?php

return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Systems\Controller\Systems' => 'Systems\Controller\SystemsController',
         ),
     ),


          // The following section is new and should be added to your file
     'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
             'systems' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/systems[/][:action][/:id]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                         'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Systems\Controller\Systems',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),

     'view_manager' => array(
         'template_path_stack' => array(
             'systems' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
         ),
     ),
 );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zendframework 2. ID paramter in SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137638/zendframework-2-id-paramter-in-sql-query)

Comment: i believe that question was to find out how to take the route id to the controller.  This question is more orientated for help in finding a way to use the route id inside the ajax call.  I think it's better to not stray off topic so it helps other people

Comment: If `$this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);` is returning `0` then the  `id` parameter **has not been found** in the route. This means it's a routing issue. Update your question with your route config and also inspect the data being sent via the ajax call and make sure that the id value is correctly being sent

Comment: I have added my route config.  The problem i see is that data is being sent correctly through the ajaxviewsystemAction.  I can see that when i visit the url ajaxviewsystemAction/343 .. However because it is being rendered through viewsystemAction no route is being passed into the ajaxviewsystem

Comment: I found a crazy little hack for a temporary fix.  I echo'd the controller into the view and passed it through the paramater string that way.  Dont believe it is the correct way but it is working fo rnow